# getRemoteUser() returns null when authenticated user visits unprotected page

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a J2EE web application with both protected pages and unprotected pages.  Once I have successfully authenticated and visited a protected page, I immediately visit an unprotected page.  At this point, getRemoteUser() returns null as if I had never authenticated.  Is this expected behavior with respect to J2EE security?

I've taken a look at the servlet spec (2.4) and the security section of the J2EE tutorial (1.4), and I haven't been able to find any comment specifically on whether accessing an unprotected resource should preserve the user's authentication state.

Edit: I'm invoking getRemoteUser() on the current HttpServletRequest object immediately before rendering the unprotected page.

Edit: I've also checked the JavaDoc for HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() and HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal(), and they do not comment on this issue either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using JAAS (ex: [JOSSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOSSO)), It falls under [RFC-2617 HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html).

Then it comes down to whether the client sends credentials with the request. For basic auth, that is based on the URI of the request that required credentials. When you access a path outside that branch of the tree, credentials are not sent unless a 401 is encountered.

So, yes, I'd expect a null.